# Failed to load page using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, iis-8

I've to ASP.NET web sites hosted by newest IIS. Both of them are written using 4.5.2 framework and mvc 5. 
When I try to convert one of them:

```
.\wkhtmltopdf.exe "http://localhost:6001" out.pdf
```

Everything is ok. But another one:

```
.\wkhtmltopdf.exe "http://localhost:6000" out.pdf
```

causes problem:

> Failed loading page http://localhost:6000

In the second sample, even action is not hit. Why it happens? Some solutions?

I've tried `--load-error-handling` flag - no luck.

What's more strange, IIS Tracing is not registering any request to the server when calling `wkhtmltopdf`.

**EDIT:**

Problem solved. I've changed port from 6000 to 5999... and worked. Strange. It looks like that `wkhtmltopdf` handled port `6000` in a special way.

Comment: does `http://localhost:6000` load in the browser?

Comment: yeep, without any problems.